# Suspected alien life in a black hole

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, black-hole

This was in a short story I read ten to twenty years ago.

A scientific research starship is investigating a black hole. One of the researchers maintains that he is receiving faint intelligent signals from the black hole, apparently emitted by some alien life-form living inside the hole.

As I recall, it turns out there really is no signal, it is all a ploy in the deranged researcher's plan to do something awful to the ship. The signal was very faint, buried in the random noise from the black hole. So the  deranged researcher was using this to try and convince the captain to move the ship even closer to the black hole. If I recall correctly the deranged researcher wanted to destroy himself and one other person aboard as some kind of revenge, and didn't care that the ship and everybody else would be destroyed as well.

One unique feature of the story was the faster-than-light propulsion/communication system. It was based on human beings performing Sex Yoga. Upon command the humans would be triggered by a post-hypnotic suggestion, they would then pair off and do the yoga, which would activate their latent psychic abilities or something like that, resulting in FTL flight. The humans would have no memory of who did what to whom while they were acting as the starship's FTL drive.

One of the sex yoga crew mentioned to another that he hoped he was paired with another lady member that he found attractive. One of the officers smirked while thinking that the post-hypnotic amnesia rendered this hope foolish. Why hope to be paired with a particular person when you will have no memory?

Comment: Now that I think about it, probably not

Comment: As regards the "ship driven by sex", we just had a recent question about that. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Huh. No dice, but I could swear that somewhere in the last week or two, it was posted, with part of the question noting that they were not actually told that sex was what made the ship run due to it being a publicity issue, but the people on the ship working it out for themselves.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it was [Sci-Fi short story possibly from a “Best of” anthology from the 1950s-60s about a space voyage with a secret engine activated via sex](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198096/sci-fi-short-story-possibly-from-a-best-of-anthology-from-the-1950s-60s-about) but I don't think it's related to this book.

Comment: As I recall, the researchers on board the ship are essentially slaves of a dystopian government, and the researcher's hope is to escape into the black hole with another of the researchers. The crew were as unattractive as the government, so hard to blame him! But he fails.